# Problema con variables Date en Spring Boot - Angular 6

Tags: mysql, json, angular, spring

Al tratar datos de tipo `Date` estoy teniendo problemas. En el servidor (`Spring Boot`) estoy recogiendo de `MySQL` un campo Date, y esta información al Debuguear es correcta en el Modelo de Spring Boot. Pero si veo esa llamada por fuera, el **JSON** generado tiene este campo como **TimeStamp**. Supongo que el error principal es este, pero si más tarde en Angular intento parsear esta variable a Date y hago un typeof, me devuelve que la variable es un `Object`.

¿Alguna idea? Dejo el código a continuación:

[SPRING BOOT]:

Modelo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PATIENTS")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Patient {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(name="gender")
private String gender;

@Column(name="birthdate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date birthdate;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public Date getBirthdate() {
    return birthdate;
}

public void setBirthdate(Date birthdate) {
    this.birthdate = birthdate;
}
}
```

Código Controlador:

```
/**
 * Obtenemos el modelo Patient a partir de su Id
 * @param id
 * @return
 */
@GetMapping("/patients/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> getPatient(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {

    logger.debug("Llamada al método getPatient()");

    Patient patient = patientService.getPatient(id);

    if(patient == null) {
        logger.error("No se ha encontrado al usuario " + id);
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<Patient>(patient, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Código Service: (método getOne de JpaRepository)

```
public Patient getPatient(Long id) {
    return patientDao.getOne(id);
}
```

[JSON]:

```
{"id":1,"gender":"F","birthdate":846194400000}
```

[ANGULAR 6]:

Servicio:

```
public getAllPatients() {
return this.http.get<Patient[]>(this._baseURL + '/all');
}
```

Modelo:

```
export class Patient {

id: number;
gender: string;
birthdate: Date;

constructor() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto a `typeof` la documentación dice:

> El operador typeof devuelve una cadena que indica el tipo del operando
>   sin evaluarlo.

De los cuales puede regresar:

1. function
2. string
3. number
4. object
5. undefined
6. boolean

Por lo que es normal que te regrese como salida `'object'`.

Por otra parte si deseas recibir el campo formateado como una fecha puede agregar lo siguiente a tu archivo `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
```

O en su respectivo formato en caso de utilizar un `application.yml`.

Con esto logras que el resultado sea de la siguiente forma:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "gender": "X",
    "birthdate": "2018-11-23"
}
```

En la versión 2.1.0 de *Spring Boot* este parámetro ya viene por defecto a `true` en cuyo caso el resultado se muestra de la siguiente forma:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "gender": "X",
    "birthdate": "2018-11-24T02:32:09.673+0000"
}
```

Cuyos formatos ya puedes trabajar adecuadamente con *javascript*, por ejemplo:

```
new Date("2018-11-24T02:32:09.673+0000")
Fri Nov 23 2018 20:32:09 GMT-0600 (hora estándar central)

new Date("2018-11-23")
Thu Nov 22 2018 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (hora estándar central)
```

### Referencias

1. [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/typeof)
2. [`WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)

Comment: Buenas, he intentado esa configuración y sigue apareciendome igual. No sé qué podría ser....

Answer (score 0):

En tu model de Spring boot puedes usar el [JsonFormat](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonformat)

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone = "America/Asuncion")
private Date birthdate;
```

En tu angular puedes hacerle el tratamiento que quieras

```
// Importar DatePipe
import { DatePipe } from "@angular/common";

// antes del constructor
public birthdate: string;
public datePipe: DatePipe;
```

--

```
// en tu funcion
const datepipe: DatePipe = new DatePipe('en-PY');
this.birthdate = datepipe.transform(row.birthdate, 'dd-MM-YYYY')
```

o tal vez ya por binding en tu html

```
{{ row?.birthdate | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
```